# Sliding an xib(view) from top to bottom while we drag

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiview

I have a Main view with an image on top of it.When I touch the image & drag it downwards, another view(Menu View), along with this image, should get displayed as SLIDING from top to bottom with the speed I drag the image.

When I stop dragging,the sliding also should halt.

If I release the dragging after half of the screen,the sliding should continue to bottom of the screen.

How could I achieve this ?
I have tried,downloaded and edited code from the following links :
http://code4app.com/ios/JCFlipPageView/53e4aacb933bf067598b5618
http://code4app.com/ios/CBHazeTransitionViewController/534cb5f8933bf06b108b4a7a

But they were unable to satisfy the requirements as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple.

Put all the views you want to move together inside another view. Place them at their starting position. Make the container view have it's opaque flag set to false, and a background color of clearColor. Set it's userInteractionEnabled flag to YES.

If you're using auto-layout, add a vertical constraint that places them at their starting position. Control-drag from your constraint to your VC's header file and create an outlet for the constraint.

Add a pan gesture recognizer to the view that is going to be dragged down. On start of the pan gesture, record the starting Y position.

As the gesture moves, add the change in the Y position to the dragged view's Y position. (Or to the dragged view's vertical constraint's constant, if using AutoLayout.)

Comment: I have added panGestureRecogniser for an UIImageView named header.
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];

[header addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

and the 'move' method starts as follows :

-(void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

When I debugged,the control is not reaching the method 'move'.
Had I gone wrong anywhere ?

Comment: You said you wanted you image view and a new view (Menu View) to be dragged down at the same time. You should enclose all the views that you want to move in a parent view. The thing you are probably missing is setting `userInteractionEnabled=YES` on the view that you want to drag.